# Which Intel CPUs do not have Management Engine (ME)

Tags: windows, linux, backdoor, cpu, intel

The Intel Management Engine (ME) is a security risk which I would prefer not to take. I do not trust it, it seems to be a backdoor, and there are reported vulnerabilities on it.

I do not trust the neutering process to either partially, or fully, remove it. Additionally, it is also becoming more difficult to find CPUs which are compatible with the neutering process. Most I have found are expensive, as security concerned people are purchasing them.

Telling me that Intel will remove this for government bodies, like the military, is not a valid answer, as I am an individual.

Could someone provide me with a list of which Intel CPUs do not have the Management Engine? Wikipedia said since 2008 all Intel CPUs have included them, but I was hoping for a more reputable source.

EDIT: Based on the comments below, feel free to instead provide the fastest Intel CPU which does not have ME.

Comment: *"Could someone provide me with a list... "* - Which CPU support which feature are public available information. Compiling a list from this might be tedious but is not actually a problem which cannot be done by doing your own research, so you basically just try to outsource your own work to others. [Using a search engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=list+of+cpu+without+management+engine) will help you to collect these information faster.

Comment: No Intel CPU comes without it. UEFI will not bootstrap without it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I was not necessarily asking for a list if one is not available online, but perhaps knowing where to start looking. The Wikipedia article says CPUs before 2008 did not have ME, but I have found several that do have it. So just a point in the right direction, any hints, tips etc... to make it easier for me to do my own research.

Comment: @defalt You are living in the now, but from around 2006 or before the CPUs did not have ME, back in the days of BIOS.

Comment: Everyone, it appears Intel Pentium D is the newest Intel CPU without ME, but I was hoping someone could confirm this.

Comment: This really isn't a security question. This is a hardware question.

Answer (score 1):

> Which Intel CPUs do not have Management Engine (ME)

None that I'm aware of, however:

IME in the CPU itself is innocuous unless it's accompanied by the respective motherboard firmware and here comes the solution: you can edit your motherboard firmware to remove IME. There are multiple projects involved in that:

- https://github.com/mostav02/Remove_IntelME_FPT
- https://github.com/oood/How-to-Disable-Intel-ME-on-Intel-NUCs
- https://github.com/bol-van/me-disable
- https://github.com/darajnish/dell5577medisable

Also some motherboards allow to disable Intel ME in BIOS settings. I cannot vouch it's 100% foolproof and cannot be reenabled by e.g. Windows Updates or bad actors but it's been proven to work.

Comment: Intel Pentium D from 2005 appears not to have IME...

Comment: This could be the case but that CPU is extremely slow by today's standards, motherboards for it lack NVMe slots and I'm not even sure SATA ports were ubiquitous back then. You can buy such a system from eBay of course for pennies but its usability is at best questionable.

Comment: There are some pretty good YouTube videos on using Windows 98 in 2023, it might take a day in setting up hardware and software, but you can still browse modern websites etc...

Comment: Using such an outdated OS with a deprecated unsupported web browser is a recipe for getting hacked almost in no time. Intel ME in comparison is a fortress.

Comment: Just use Sandboxie to sandbox the web browser? Also, I am sure there are some modern Linux distros that are designed to work on outdated hardware, Puppy Linux comes to mind.

Comment: Sandboxie doesn't protect against this type of vulnerabilities. Transient execution CPU vulnerabilities even allow OS'es running under a VM access full host RAM (if mitigations are not enabled and e.g. many Linux users run to love with `mitigations=off`).

Comment: I disagree. Sandboxie to sandbox the web browser will stop the majority of realistic attacks. Transient execution vulnerabilities, like Spectre, are not applicable to such as CPUs like the Intel Pentium D. I would leave mitigations enabled.